# SharePoint list updated column names not showing up through web services

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am using the `GetListItems()` method in Lists.asmx on a SharePoint 2007 server.  I have noticed that when a column's name is changed in SharePoint, the web service continues to send back the column's original name instead of the new name.

I understand this is generally a good thing, but what can I do to get the service to send me the updated column name when that's what I want?  Other than creating a new column, copying data, and deleting the original column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `GetListItems()` uses **internal names** that do not change once the column is created. Check the [SharePoint Internal name, Static name, Display name](http://blogs.blumshapiroconsulting.com/jjkblog/archive/2010/09/07/sharepoint-internal-name-static-name-display-name.aspx) article for more details.

Use the [Lists.GetList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlist%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method to retrieve list schema - it contains both `Name` and `DisplayName`:

```
<Fields>
  <Field ColName="tp_ID" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Counter" Name="ID" PrimaryKey="TRUE" DisplayName="ID" FromBaseType="TRUE" />
<Fields>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like I have to prepend `ows_` to the name retrieved by `GetList()` to find a column when using `GetListItems()`.